# How do I use xpath in a GET request?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, yql

I'm trying to get some text using YQL, but from what I can tell the quotes in my xpath are messing things up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>le test</p>
<p>
<script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url='http://www.lethbridgecollege.ca/program/administrative-office-professional' and xpath='//*[@id="node-1075"]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]'"></script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The URL works fine if you drop it in the address bar in a browser, but as soon as you put it inside of some quotes ("") as the script src, then the `xpath='//*[@id="node-1075"]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]'` gets messed up. What can I do to fix this?

What can I do different so the call will work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode the parameters of your request.  The URL works when you paste it in to the address bar because the browser is smart enough to URL encode characters that shouldn't be in the URL.  The proper url is:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lethbridgecollege.ca%2Fprogram%2Fadministrative-office-professional%27%20and%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22node-1075%22%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B1%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fp%5B2%5D%27
```

You can read about URL encoding here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding